# Combining lists values for displaying in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to display a result from few calls to some device's API in django template. But I'm having troubles on how to pass the results to the template and display them in a way I want.

I have three corresponding lists.
List of pools as an initial input for query (the amount of pools is not fixed):

```
pools_list = ['testpoolA', 'testpoolB']
```

List of members retrieved from first API call (get each pool's member list):

```
members_lists = [
 [{'address': '10.10.10.11', 'port': 1616},
  {'address': '10.10.10.11', 'port': 1717},
  {'address': '10.10.10.12', 'port': 1616},
  {'address': '10.10.10.12', 'port': 1717}],
 [{'address': '10.20.20.11', 'port': 1212},
  {'address': '10.20.20.11', 'port': 1213},
  {'address': '10.20.20.12', 'port': 1212},
  {'address': '10.20.20.12', 'port': 1213}]
]
```

List of members priorities from second API call (get each members priority from each pool):

```
members_priorites_lists = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

And I'd like to display this as:

Pool name1:

- pool1 member1 addres, port, priority
- pool1 member2 addres, port, priority
  (...)

Pool name2:

- pool2 member1 addres, port, priority
- pool2 member2 addres, port, priority
  (...)

In python I could do this with nested loops with shared index.
But from what I've read so far it's not possible in django template (to keep logic from it as much as possible).

So how can I do this? I guess I'll need to prepare the data structure somehow in a view and then pass it to the template in some different form (some prepared dictionary?). But I'm not sure how to build it and then access it in the template.
What would be the best way to approach this? I would really appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know an easy way to traverse multiple lists at the same time with this level of complexity, however, you can do the following in your view:

```
>>> for i, members in enumerate(members_lists):
...     for j, member in enumerate(members):
...         member["priority"] = members_priorites_lists[i][j]
... return render(request, "main.html", {"members": zip(pools_list, members_lists)})
```

Then in the template;

```
{% for pool, members_list in members %}
  Pool name: {{pool}}
  {% for member in members_list %}
    {{member.address}}, {{member.port}}, {{member.priority}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That was an excellent tip. It gets me exactly the result I wanted. Thank you!